# Long-running transactions structured approach

Tags: transactions, xa

I'm looking for a structured approach to long-running (hours or more) transactions. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425742/best-way-to-manage-transactions), these type of interactions are usually handled by optimistic locking and manual merge strategies.

It would be very handy to have some more structured approach to this type of problem using standard transactions. Various long-running interactions such as user registration, order confirmation etc. all have transaction-like semantics, and it is both error-prone and tedious to invent your own fragile manual roll-back and/or time-out/clean-up strategies.

Taking a RDBMS as an example, I realize that it would be a major performance cost associated with keeping all the transactions open. As an alternative, I could imagine having a database supporting two isolation levels/strategies simultaneously, one for short-running and one for long-running conversations. Long-running conversations could then for instance have more strict limitations on data access to facilitate them taking more time (read-only semantics on some data, optimistic locking semantics etc).

Are there any solutions which could do something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RDBMS ACID transactions belong always to short, atomic and local operations. Distributed application, autonomus services, loosely coupled components use different strategies like rentention and compensating transactions.

A good read on this topic are [Pat Helland's](http://blogs.msdn.com/pathelland/) papers, he's been teaching about this subject since the 80s. See for instance [Architecture of an Autonomous Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164125.aspx) or [Fiefdoms and Emissaries](http://download.microsoft.com/documents/uk/msdn/architecture/connected/Fiefdoms_Emissaries.ppt).

Comment: I read both these articles, and although I fully agree with the concepts and found them quite funny :), I was more looking for tools making these things happen. I find that the compensating operations could be implemented with the help of the datasource for instance (they look a lot like transactions). The optimistic locking strategies employed to deal with the stale data from the Emissaries could be supported by the datasource as well. So in essence, thank you for great articles, but are there any tools which support this type of architecture, or do you have to do it all manually?

Comment: Not realy. The tools I've been wroking on for years asa dev, Service Broker, had these concepts in its design, see http://bit.ly/4DDTZ5 for example. But to that is a very narrow and specialized example, far from a  generic solutoin supported by the development toolset. In the MS stack the WCF and the Synch Framework have such objectives on their agenda, but I wouldn't venture to claim that an actual solution exists (ahem ... or that it ever will). On the JEE stack they seem to grok this problems better, but I'm not familiar enough with that tool stack to give a verdict.

Comment: Although I found both your and Pascals answer good, I'm going to accept yours, since it illustrated the problems better, and I think that BPM is only a part of the answer. The real problem seem to be that you indeed need to build your app to support this behavior, as seen with temporary flight bookings, reservations in bank systems etcetera. The links you provided provided a good starting point.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483286/understanding-data-outside-of-service-soa ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use a BPM tool for such kind of things, there are explicitly intended to support long-running orchestrations. I can't elaborate right but suggest to check [Understanding BPM Servers](http://www.davidchappell.com/writing/Understanding_BPM_Servers.pdf). I'm quoting some parts below but the whole paper is worth the read:

> **Managing an Orchestration's State**
>
> One of the biggest differences between
>   an orchestration and the business
>   services it uses  is the time each
>   takes to execute. A request to a
>   typical service generates a reply
>   within a  few seconds. Because it
>   commonly drives all or part of a
>   business process, however, an 
>   orchestration may run for hours, days,
>   or weeks, depending on how long the
>   process  takes to finish. What if
>   human approval is required at some
>   point in the process, for  instance,
>   and the person who must give her
>   approval is on vacation? Because
>   business  processes can take a long
>   time to complete, the orchestrations
>   that control them can also  run for a
>   long time.
>
> This long-running nature affects how
>   an orchestration manages the in-memory
>   information  it maintains—the
>   state—about a running process. If the
>   orchestration is blocked for a 
>   significant period of time, keeping
>   this state in memory doesn’t make much
>   sense.  Instead, a BPM server should
>   provide a way for an orchestration’s
>   state to be  automatically written to
>   disk, then restored again when the
>   business process resumes,  even if
>   it’s days or weeks later.
>
> State management illustrates another
>   notable difference between BPM servers
>   and  application servers. Since
>   supporting long-running business
>   processes isn’t their primary purpose,
>   application servers haven’t
>   traditionally addressed this kind of
>   state  management. Because they are
>   explicitly intended to support
>   long-running orchestrations,  however,
>   BPM servers do provide this service.
>
> **Handling Transactions**
>
> Many business processes require the
>   all-or-nothing behavior characterized
>   by a  transaction. For example, an
>   orchestration driving a business
>   process might need to  invoke two
>   business services and ensure that
>   either both requests succeed or both
>   fail.  This kind of atomic transaction
>   can be accomplished using a standard
>   two-phase commit  protocol, and it’s
>   something that BPM servers typically
>   support. In fact, application servers 
>   include this feature, so a BPM server
>   built on an application server can
>   offer this quite  easily.
>
> The nature of many business processes
>   raises another issue, however. What if
>   a  particular process requires
>   all-or-nothing behavior, but a
>   traditional atomic transaction isn’t 
>   possible? Atomic transactions require
>   locking data for the life of the
>   transaction, something  that isn’t a
>   problem when the transaction is short.
>   But suppose the services that must be 
>   bundled into an all-or-nothing group
>   include one that requires human
>   approval. Even if the  required
>   approver isn’t on vacation, the time
>   it takes for a person to respond is
>   likely far too  long for data to
>   remain locked. Or what if one service
>   that must be in this transactional 
>   group doesn’t participate in atomic
>   transactions? This isn’t a far-fetched
>   worry, since many  applications won’t
>   let arbitrary clients lock their data.
>
> To handle situations like these, a BPM
>   server supports long-running
>   transactions. Also called business
>   activities and other names,
>   long-running transactions handle
>   errors not by rolling back all
>   updates, but rather by executing some
>   kind of compensating logic when an
>   error occurs. For example, suppose a
>   particular long-running transaction
>   includes an atomic transaction that
>   transfers money from one bank to
>   another, followed by an operation that
>   executes another application once the
>   transfer has succeeded. If this final
>   operation fails, the logic of the
>   business process requires that the
>   money transfer be undone. Yet the
>   atomic transaction that performed this
>   transfer has already committed— how
>   can it be reversed? The answer is that
>   compensating logic must run if a
>   failure occurs, logic that might
>   execute another atomic transaction to
>   undo the effects of the transfer. A
>   BPM server provides built-in
>   facilities that allow the creator of
>   an orchestration to define this
>   compensating action, then have it
>   automatically execute when a long-
>   running transaction fails.
>
> While compensation is useful when
>   atomic transactions aren’t possible,
>   it’s not without problems. Suppose an
>   orchestration modifies some data in
>   the early part of a long-running
>   transaction, for instance, then runs a
>   compensating operation later to change
>   this data back to its original state.
>   What happens if some other application
>   accesses that data in between these
>   two events? This second application
>   may well use data that’s ultimately
>   deemed to be incorrect in making
>   business decisions, such as computing
>   credit risk. Or think about operations
>   for which there is no obvious
>   compensation. If an orchestration
>   causes a missile to be launched,
>   there’s no way for compensating code
>   in that orchestration to reverse this.
>   Yet while compensation isn’t a perfect
>   solution, it is nevertheless the right
>   approach for an important category of
>   problems faced by business processes.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how that helps? Thanks